# OpenGL/Android big sprite quads bad performance

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, alpha, sprite

I am developping a game on android using opengl and am having a little performance problem.

Let's say for example I want to draw a background partially filled with grass "bushes".  Bushes have different x,y,z, different sizes and so on (each bush is a 2D sprite), and potentially partially hide each other (I use a perspective camera).  I am having a big performance problem if those sprites are big (i.e. the quad sizes, not the texture size/resolution) :

- If I use a classical front to back draw (to avoid overdraw), I find myself having problems because of (I think) alpha testing. Even if the bushes have only opaque and fully transparent pixels (no partial transparency), and if I use the proper alpha testing comparison (GL_EQUAL 1) the performances are bad because a lot of pixels have to be alpha tested (If I understand right).
- If I use a back to front display with alpha testing disabled, I lose a lot of performance too (but this time because of overdraw problems), even when disabling depth buffer writing (not sure if it does anything if depth test is disabled by the way).

I am having good performances if using front to back without alpha testing, but of course sprite cutout is completely gone, which is really really bad.

All the bushes have the same texture, I use 16 bit colors, mip mapping, geometry batching, cull faces, no shaders,  etc. All what I can think of to improve performances (which are not bad in other cases), except texture compression. I even filter the sprites to avoid "displaying" the ones out the screen. I have also tried some "violent optimizations" for test purposes, such as making the textures fully opaque, lowering the texture resolution a lot, disabling blending,  etc, but nothing was fantastic performance-wise except the alpha testing removal.

I was wondering if I was forgetting something here to help with the performance. Back to front creates overdraw, front to back is slow because of alpha testing (and I do not want my bushes to be "square" images so I cannot disable alpha testing). If I create smaller sprites performances are far better (even with a lot more sprites), but this is only a workaround.

**To summarize**, how can you display overlapping big quads needing cutout, without losing performance?

*PS :* I am testing on a nexus one.

*PS2* : Some optimizations suggest to not create quads but geometries more "fitting" the texture, but it seems to be a really tedious process, and would not help me a lot I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing front-to-back is normally a benefit because of early-z: the hardware can do the depth test right after rasterization, before doing the texture fetch or shading. With front-to-back sorting, most fragments fail the depth test, and you save a lot of texture bandwidth, shading throughput, and zbuffer-write bandwidth.

But alpha test breaks that. If a fragment passes the depth test, it might still be killed by alpha test, so zwrite can't happen until after texturing/shading. Most hardware that can do early-z still has to do the depth test at the same point in the pipeline as it does zwrite, so with alpha test you end up doing ztest + zwrite after texturing and shading. As a result, front-to-back sorting only saves you zwrite bandwidth, nothing else.

I think you have two options, if you really want large sprites that overlap significantly:

(a) Only use two or three distinct Z values for your sprites. Draw them back-to-front with blending (and alpha-test, if it helps). No overlap within a layer: you can pre-render each layer either in the original assets or once at runtime, then just shift it left and right.

(b) If your sprites have large opaque regions surrounded by a semi-transparent border, you can draw the opaque regions in a first pass with no alpha test, then draw borders as a separate pass. This will cut down on the number of alpha-tested fragments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I was actually unaware of alpha test spoiling front to back sorting benefits that much.